# MongoDB collection.find({}) request returning empty array

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, mern

I have a MERN stack application.  I am using mongoDB and mongoose to store and access a database in the backend. The database was working fine until today when I was prompted to whitelist my IP address for database access... I presumed there was some IP refresh and so I did so on the mongoDB website. Since then, I am connecting to the database smoothly from my app, but the find({}) request is only returning an empty array.

I have overcome the pluralization issue using the collection parameter in the schema, so this shouldn't be the issue.

**models/NZfirmModel.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema  = mongoose.Schema

const NZFirmSchema = new Schema({
    ...
}, { collection : 'new-zealand' })

module.exports = mongoose.model('NZFirm', NZFirmSchema)
```

**controllers/firmController.js**

```
const NZFirmModel = require('../models/NZfirmModel')

const getNZFirms = async (req, res) => {
    const firms = await NZFirmModel.find({})
    res.status(200).json(firms)
}

module.exports = {
    getNZFirms,
}
```

**routes/firms.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const {
    getNZFirms,
    getNZFirm,
    getAUSFirms,
    getAUSFirm
} = require('../controllers/firmController')

const router = express.Router()

router.get('/new-zealand', getNZFirms)

module.exports = router
```

**server.js**

```
require('dotenv').config()

const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const firmRoutes = require('./routes/firms')

// express app
const app = express()

// middleware
app.use(express.json())

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.path, req.method)
  next()
})

// routes
app.use('/api/firms', firmRoutes)

// connect to db
mongoose.set("strictQuery", false);
mongoose.connect(`${process.env.MONGODB_AP_URI}/asia-pacific`)
    .then(() => {
        // listen for requests
        app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
        console.log(`connected to asia-pacific db and listening on port ${process.env.PORT}`)
    })
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
    })
```

**Database Layout**

```
asia-pacific
     |->  new-zealand
```

**Console Output**

```
/api/firms/new-zealand GET
```

**Postman Output Following GET Request**

```
[]
```

Is there something else at play here? It's worth noting that when I specify the collection name in the model export, nothing changes.  Furthermore, my API requests were working perfectly before I re-whitelisted my IP address, so the schema must be correct.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: OP here, (of course I solve the problem minutes after posting this question... typical!) I just happened to check over the list of IP addresses with access to the database and it was very cluttered. I cleared the list and allowed only my IP which seems to have solved the problem.